# Querying compressed files using BigQuery federated source

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

According to the BigQuery federated source [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/federated-data-sources#limitations):

> [...]or are **compressed** must be less than 1 GB each.

This would imply that compressed files are supported types for federated sources in BigQuery.

However, I get the following error when trying to query a `gz` file in GCS:

[image]

I tested with an uncompressed file and it works fine. Are compressed files supported as federated sources in BigQuery, or have I misinterpreted the documentation?

Comment: You certainly shouldn't be getting an internal error (although there might be something else wrong). I'll file a bug with the team and get back to you when I have some additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compression mode defaults to NONE and needs to be explicitly specified in the external table definition.

At the time of the question, this couldn't be done through the UI. This is now fixed and compressed data should be automatically detected.

For more background information, see:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query

The interesting parameter is "configuration.query.tableDefinitions.[key].compression".